# PHP adding 2 extra bytes to my uploaded file

Tags: php, upload

I have a process that uploads files via PHP but the resulting files end up being 2 bytes larger than the source file.  I'm not sure where these 2 bytes are coming from. (the actual process is a chunked upload where I slice up a file and upload the slices, each slice winds up arriving 2 bytes longer than it started, but I've tested with a single small file and it too arrives 2 bytes larger than the source).

I'm attaching my PHP... Is this a normal feature of PHP? I'm imagining some sort of null terminator or something (there does appear to be a \n at the end of each file that wasn't there initially).  Do I need to read the file into a buffer and get rid of the last two bytes before reassembling my original? I have to imagine I'm doing something wrong, but I'm confounded as to what it would be.

If I do need to manually strip off those last two bytes what's the correct way to do that (it's a binary file) and then append the rest to the overall file I'm rebuilding?

---

EDIT

---

Each uploaded file is getting a 0D0A word added to the end as PHP saves it to the server. So... I guess the question is how to prevent this from happening.

```
<?PHP
$target_path = $_REQUEST[ 'path' ];
$originalFileName = $_REQUEST['original_file_name'];
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'name' ] );

if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'Filedata' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $target_path ) )
{

        $newFilePath = $originalFileName; //this is the overall file being re-assembled
        $fh = fopen($newFilePath, 'ab') or die("can't open file");

        $nextSlice = file_get_contents($target_path); //this is the slice that's 2 bytes too big each time

        fputs($fh, $nextSlice);
        fclose($fh);

//      unlink($target_path); //normally I'd delete the slice at this point, but I'm hanging on to it while I figure out where the heck the 2 extra bytes are coming from.

        fclose($fh);

        echo "SUCCESS";

}
else
{
     echo "FAIL:There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like a BOM (Byte Order Mark). What encoding is the file?

Comment: If you replace `fputs` with `fwrite` does the problem go away? (I know they're *supposed* to be synonyms, but at least in C `fputs` adds a newline to the output; so it's possible that the PHP function has a bug making it add the newline...)

Comment: `fputs($fh, $nextSlice, count($nextSlice) - 2)` ?

Comment: I'm uploading using AS3 URLRequest. I'm not changing the encoding, so, whatever the native encoding of that class is, I guess. I didn't think it would make a difference as I'm doing a binary upload, I thought encoding was irrelevant at that point.

Comment: When does the size change (\r\n added)?  Is it different after move_uploaded_file()? or not until you run file_get_contents()? Or it is when you write it out that the \r\n is added?  My hunch is that the browser is adding it, you'll have to strip it out upon receipt.

Comment: move_uploaded_file adds the 2 bytes (I had neglected to check that first... good catch!)

Comment: move_uploaded_file is doing it? That's weird.... you could either chop them back off, or try a combination of `is_uploaded_file`, `copy`, and `unlink` instead.

Comment: So, the solution (albeit ugly) is to just remove the last two bytes of the incoming file.  I suspect there is something else going on, that's less than perfect, but for the time being that does do the trick. I'll leave this question open for a bit more.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: You're sure it's `move_uploaded_file` that's doing it now? It could be happening even before that you know... check the file length of the temp file, `$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']`. Also, did you try different browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be this:

fwrite($fh, $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);

I may be doing something wrong in my request that when I use the method I described in the question, the file gets written with the extra 0D0A at the end, but the above method for extracting the data has it arriving intact and exactly the right length.

Answer (score 1):

Is the file binary? I'm thinking that `file_get_contents` is causing problems because it's treating it like a string. Maybe you should try [fread](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) instead?

Comment: that sounded promising, but no dice... same result. I should note that looking at hex edit, the last word of my original file is 0D0A and I'm seeing that the last two words (with the one extra word) is a repetition of that (0D0A 0D0A).  I'll test now to see if that could be a coincidence (highly unlikely).

Comment: CrLF... what does that mean? I'm not sure what to do about it... I don't want it there... it's not part of what I'm sending :)

Comment: @Dr Dredel carriage return, line feed aka \r\n

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: It means you are running on Windows (ugh) and didn't include the `b` flag for file reads, thus making the C file api translate linefeeds into windows linebreaks.

Comment: The only windows anywhere near this entire enterprise are the ones overlooking the bay on my left :)  I'm running my PHP on MAMP on my mac.  The file being uploaded is going up in binary form, and I can see that there is definitely no new line at the end of the slices, so, they're definitely being added by the PHP for some reason. Someone suggested that fputs is adding it, but I just changed to fwrite and it's still there. My suspicion is that the temp file is being stored this way? But I'm still at a loss.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Macs used to have a similar conversion scheme. Check your `PHP_EOL`. Otherwise this would indicate a problem with the multipart/form-data request body (e.g. client didn't send a content-length: field).